# How to generate Child objects each time a parent object is created automatically on rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application i have the following models:

```
class Bus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :seats, dependent: :destroy
end

class Seat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bus
end
```

Is there a way to have a specific number of "Seats" created each time a user adds a bus? I don't want users to be creating seats for the buses.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do it. Did you try anything?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object) for this purpose, specifically `after_create` one.

```
class Bus
  DEFAULT_SEATS_COUNT = 50.freeze

  after_create :add_seats

  private

  def add_seats
    DEFAULT_SEATS_COUNT.times do
      # This logic can be more complicated if you need different attribute values for different seats.
      self.seats.create!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hook creation of child object to `after_create` callback
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord

    # register callback
    after_create :createChilds

    private

    def createChilds
        # create required amount of childs
    end
end
```